# Find inflection points of $\frac{\cos x}{x}$

Tags: calculus

We have following function

> $$\frac{\cos x}{x}$$

I would like to have find inflection points of the function above

First derivative

$$f'(x) = \frac{-x\sin x - \cos x}{x^2}$$

Second derivative

$$f''(x) = \frac{(-x\sin x - \cos x)'x^2 - (-x\sin x - \cos x)(x^2)'}{(x^2)'} \implies $$

$$f''(x) = \frac{((-\sin x - x\cos x) + \sin x)x^2 - (-x\sin x - \cos x)2x}{x^4}$$

Setting numerator to zero

$$((-\sin x - x\cos x) + \sin x)x^2 - (-x\sin x - \cos x)2x = 0$$

Simplifying
$$(- x\cos x)x^2 - (-x\sin x - \cos x)2x = 0 \implies$$
$$- x^3\cos x - (-2x^2\sin x - 2x\cos x) = 0 \implies$$
$$- x^3\cos x + 2x^2\sin x + 2x\cos x = 0$$

We can factor out $-x$:

$$-x(x^2\cos x - 2x\sin x - 2\cos x) = 0$$

Since $\frac{\cos x}{x}$ is undefined at zero, we can just consider what's inside the brackets:
$$x^2\cos x - 2x\sin x - 2\cos x = 0$$

Further attempt to simplify (divide everything by $\cos x$):

$$x^2 - 2x\tan x - 2 = 0$$

And now I'm stuck. What should I do next?

Comment: Just wondering, is this an exercise from your textbook?

Comment: @imranfat No, it is not.

Comment: I am not aware that your quadratic equation is solvable, heck it isn't even quadratic

Comment: Sympy gives up trying to solve for x. I think you're out of luck and should use numerical methods.

Comment: Have a look at my update. Quite funny ! Thanks for the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that $x\neq 0$ you properly arrived to the equation
$$\left(2-x^2\right) \cos (x)+2 x \sin (x)=0$$ which is highly transcendental and will not show explicit solutions (remember that this is already the case for $x=\cos(x)$); so, you will need some numerical methods.

Since the function is even, let us focus on the **first** positive root (there is an infinite number of roots).

Since we know the exact values of trigonometric functions of multiples of $\frac \pi {24}$, by inspection we can see that the solution is close to $x=\frac{4 \pi }{3}$.

So, using Taylor expansions, we have
$$\left(-1-\frac{4 \pi }{\sqrt{3}}+\frac{8 \pi ^2}{9}\right)-\frac{8 \pi ^2
   \left(x-\frac{4 \pi }{3}\right)}{3 \sqrt{3}}+O\left(\left(x-\frac{4 \pi
   }{3}\right)^2\right)$$ which gives as an *estimate*
$$x=\frac{4 \pi }{3}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}-\frac{3 \left(\sqrt{3}+4 \pi \right)}{8 \pi ^2}\approx 4.22287$$ while the "exact" solution would be $4.22228$.

If you really want to polish the root, starting with $x_0=\frac{4 \pi }{3}$, Newton method would give as iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 4.1887902047863909846 \\
 1 & 4.2228656054685011204 \\
 2 & 4.2222765744947805626 \\
 3 & 4.2222763997912161865 \\
 4 & 4.2222763997912008158
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

*Just for the fun of it !*

If, instead of Taylor expansion, we build around the same value the simplest $[1,1]$ Padé approximant of the function, we would get
the better approximation $$x=\frac{4 \pi }{3}+\frac{12 \pi  \left(8 \pi ^2-12 \sqrt{3} \pi-9 \right)}{14 \sqrt{3} \pi  \left(8  \pi ^2-9\right)-81}\approx 4.22226$$

**Update**

If we look at the intersections of functions $\tan(x)$ and $\frac{x^2-2}{2x}$, it is clear that the $n^{th}$ positive solution $x_{(n)}$ is closer and closer to $(2n+1)\frac \pi 2$.

So, let $x_{(n)}=(2n+1)\frac \pi 2-\epsilon$ and develop the initial equation as a Taylor series around $\epsilon=0$. Then, using series reversion we should get
$$\color{blue}{x_{(n)}=q-\frac{2}{q}-\frac{16}{3 q^3}-\frac{376}{15 q^5}-\frac{15104}{105
   q^7}-\frac{288416}{315 q^9}-\frac{7174144}{1155
   q^{11}}+O\left(\frac{1}{q^{13}}\right)}$$ where $\color{blue}{q=(2n+1)\frac \pi 2}$.

For the first solutions, the table below gives the approximation from the above formula as well as the solution obtained using Newton method.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \text{approximation} & \text{solution} \\
 1 & 4.2223930871248801802 &  4.2222763997912008158 \\
 2 & 7.5873994534002022779 &  7.5873993379940970055 \\
 3 & 10.809507299523967365 &  10.809507298160223034 \\
 4 & 13.993762567177426816 &  13.993762567126736403 \\
 5 & 17.161960091733998831 &  17.161960091730312880 \\
 6 & 20.321777248223921402 &  20.321777248223504242 \\
 7 & 23.476651054649238681 &  23.476651054649174048 \\
 8 & 26.628359164025250577 &  26.628359164025237914 \\
 9 & 29.777915914143633738 &  29.777915914143630762 \\
 10 & 32.925943175839157623 &  32.925943175839156814 \\
 11 & 36.072843767987951064 &  36.072843767987950817 \\
 12 & 39.218890250480979790 &  39.218890250480979707 \\
 13 & 42.364273708658624397 &  42.364273708658624367 \\
 14 & 45.509132115455308340 &  45.509132115455308328 \\
 15 & 48.653567604840869423 &  48.653567604840869418 \\
 16 & 51.797657409553653128 &  51.797657409553653126 \\
 17 & 54.941461020291788556 &  54.941461020291788555 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Nice and complete. I was going to do the $(2n+1)\pi/2$ stuff but you did it, and better than I would.

Comment: @martycohen. Thank you (I don't agree with *better*). There is on thing which is surprising :depending on the $n$ in the first expansion to $O(\epsilon^n)$, then the coefficients of the reversed series differ a little for the expansion in $q$. Do you mind to check if you observe the same ? Thanks & cheers.

Comment: @martycohen. Updated and quite better.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Wow, you definitely provided the complete answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Nelver. You are very welcome ! Thanks for the problem since I had a lot of fun working it. We can make the approximations more accurate at at the price of a few more $q$ terms. Cheers :-)

Comment: @Henning Makholm. Did you propose $42$ by "accident" or because it is *"Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, The Universe, and Everything"* ?